# Write a query to fetch the rows of one table plus the rows of other table not present in first table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

We have two tables:

**Product**

| ProductGuid | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

**JoinProductDocument**

| JoinProductGuid | ProductGuid |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I want to retrieve all rows in product table with an addition attribute (IsPresent) which will be 1 if that product is present in JoinProductDoucment table and 0 if it is not present.

Thanks in advance!

I tried using sql subqueries but could not figure it out.

Comment: Please show the query/queries that you tried, and include the desired results for your example data.

Comment: You can left join the JoinProductDocument table to the Product table on the ProductGuid columns, then use a CASE statement like: `CASE WHEN JoinProductDocument.ProductGuid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` for your indicator

Comment: When posting your question you were informed the following: *"Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)."* Knowing your attempt(s) will most certainly help us help you here, as we can then explain where you went wrong. You said you tried using subqueries; what were those attempts? Why didn't they work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select ProductGuid,ProductName,
       (Case when b.ProductGuid is null then 0 else 1 end) IsPresent
from Product a 
  left join JoinProductDocument b on a.ProductGuid=b.ProductGuid
```

Try this

Comment: Using aliases `a`, `b`, etc will always get a down vote from me.